# How to change navigationOptions from another class React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to change header Title of my class from another class like this:

This is a second class where, with a button, I want to change title in the first class:

```
export default class lingua extends React.Component { 
cambiolingua= () =>
{   
const registra = new Registra(); //in this class I want to change title
registra.ChangeTitle('New Title');

this.props.navigation.navigate('Registra')
}
```

And this is the first class where I need to change title:

```
export default class Registra extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
const {state} = navigation;
return {
  title: `${state.params.title}`,
};
};

 ChangeTitle = (titleText) => {
  const {setParams} = this.props.navigation;
  setParams({ title: titleText })
 }
```

But I recive error "undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.props.navigation')

How can I resolve?

Comment: Can i get snack.expo.io link?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the error is coming from the fact that you do not have the props `navigation` in you class `lingua`. This can be explains by the fact that `lingua` is not a scene in a `stackNavigator` (or any kind of navigator from react navigation).

There are 2 solutions:
1) Pass the navigation props from the screen in the stack down to this component.
2) You can use the Higher Order Component `withNavigation` of `react-navigation` to add it to `lingua`

Example:

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'

class tmp extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {navigation} = this.props; //with the withNavigation, you have access to the navigation even though it is not a screen

    return <View />
  }
}

export default withNavigation(tmp);
```

A better way to change the title than to update the navigationOptions like you do is to navigate to `Registra` by directly send the title you want to it:

```
// In lingua
this.props.navigation.navigate('Registra', {title: 'You custom title'})
```

By doing this, you don't have to call a method in Registra to update the title

Hope it helps!